# Metal Custom CIFilter different return value

Tags: ios, swift, metal, cifilter

I'm writing CIFilter, but result pixel colors are different than returned values from metal function.

kernel.metal

```
#include <CoreImage/CoreImage.h>

extern "C" { namespace coreimage {

    float4 foo(sample_t rgb){

        return float4(0.3f, 0.5f, 0.7f, 1.0f);

    }
}
```

MetalFilter.swift

```
import CoreImage

class MetalFilter: CIFilter {

    private let kernel: CIColorKernel

    var inputImage: CIImage?

    override init() {
        let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "default", withExtension: "metallib")!
        let data = try! Data(contentsOf: url)
        kernel = try! CIColorKernel(functionName: "foo", fromMetalLibraryData: data)
        super.init()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    func outputImage() -> CIImage? {
        guard let inputImage = inputImage else {return nil}
        return kernel.apply(extent: inputImage.extent, arguments: [inputImage])
    }
}
```

When I get outputImage I have these values:

R = 0.58431372549019611 

G = 0.73725490196078436 

B = 0.85490196078431369

It's some kind of post processing (like pow(x, 1/2.373) after metal function returns values.

Comment: Sounds like the texture backing your output image is sRGB-encoded.

Comment: To be clear, this is expected behavior: you return a linear-space value from your kernel, and it gets sRGB encoded to match the default color space of the output image. If you want the values in the image to be literally those you specified above, you need to manually "de-gamma" them by using the `srgb_to_linear` function before returning the value. This will cancel with the linear-to-srgb transform that happens on output. Automatic sRGB conversion is what you want most of the time, and on modern Apple GPUs, it's effectively free.

Comment: Since you are writing a custom filter I guess you already have found sucess with what I am stuck at. I am trying to apply a simple vignette filter to a live camera feed using metal. The results are pretty slow and laggy, please check this if you can tell me what is missing:https://stackoverflow.com/q/53898780/1364053

Comment: Similar question implementing sRGB to Linear: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55384641/how-to-display-mtkview-with-rgba16float-mtlpixelformat

Comment: same problem here, did u fix it?

Answer (score 4):

Core Image performs color matching two times when you process an image:
From the color space if the input image to the *working color space* of the `CIContext` and, in the final rendering step after all filters were applied, from the working color space to the *output color space* of the context.

Those color spaces are configured with default values that, in my experience, depend on the device (and its display) you are running on. However, you can define both color spaces using the [`kCIContextWorkingColorSpace`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coreimage/kcicontextworkingcolorspace?language=objc) and [`kCIContextOutputColorSpace`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coreimage/kcicontextoutputcolorspace?language=objc) options when creating your `CIContext`.

If you set both values to `NSNull()`, Core Image won't perform any color matching, treating all color values as they are in the image buffers. However, your filter probably has some assumptions on the color space of the input samples. So keep that in mind when you are dealing with inputs from sources like the camera that might have different color spaces depending on the device and camera configuration.

Another way to ensure the input samples are always in the color space you need is to set the [`kCISamplerColorSpace`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coreimage/kcisamplercolorspace) option when creating a `CISampler` that serves as input to your custom kernel.